# .net publishing

Tags: .net, winforms, deployment, clickonce

I have a .net application and i published in the local location. while installing from the published location the application need to install in "c:\temp" how can i do this in clickonce method?

Answer (score 2):

ClickOnce installers **do not install** to the "Program Files" or to any specific directory (C:\temp). For security purposes, your WinForms app is in the **ClickOnce cache**, an obfuscated directory that differs for each ClickOnce app.

It's documented in this MSDN Library topic: [ClickOnce Cache Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/267k390a.aspx) (MSDN article).

If you want to get the **data directory** programmatically, you can use the System.Deployment namespace: [ApplicationDeployment: DataDirectory Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.datadirectory.aspx) (MSDN documentation).

Answer (score 1):

ClickOnce installation always installs in the predefined user folders, the ClickOnce cache.

There is no way to install a ClickOnce program somewhere else. Neither can you decide on a different location on creation of the ClickOnce package, nor can the person installing the program decide on a different location.

This is not an omission, neither an error, it is by design and it is meant to be that way.

If you want to install in a specific location, you'll need to use some other installation method.